# Delay between request and response in netty application

Tags: java, httprequest, netty

I have got a handler which extends `SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpRequest>`. It is needed to make a delay before sending a response for a specific request and I use for this the next code in the method `channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpRequest msg)`:

```
ctx.executor().schedule(() -> ctx.write(response), 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Also note that you may need to flush the write (for instance by using writeAndFlush).

Comment: @HåkenLid I meant that it didn't produce any result, but when I changed .write() to .writeAndFlush() according to Frederic Bregier proposition it worked

Comment: @FredericBrégier can you explain to me please, why didn't it work before, because there is also a method `channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) { ctx. flush(); }` in my handler?

Comment: Not sure 100%, but I could guess that chanelReadComplete could occur before the 3 second delay, so that flush() occurs before the write, therefore not flushing your last write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to change it to:

```
ctx.executor().schedule(() -> ctx.writeAndFlush(response), 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: ty @Norman, already done! can you explain to me please, why didn't it work before, because there is also a method `channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) { ctx.flush(); }` in my handler?

Comment: As I suggestions, channelReadComplete startups as soon as you finish your read method, so long time (3 seconds) before the write, therefore your channelReadComplete flush nothing...

Comment: @FredericBrégier can you please help me with another problem: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771800/calculation-of-written-and-read-bytes-in-netty-application?noredirect=1#comment51474294_31771800>

Comment: @TMS I try to post an answear and a link to an example. Hoping it is clear enough...